# Using XACML to express policy which is a logical expression

Tags: authorization, access-control, policy, xacml, alfa

I am very new to XACML. And I am using XACML to express policy. But I can't find any good examples except a few from the [OASIS XACML Technical Committee](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.pdf).

Ok, here is my question:

I want to express policy using XACML. Users can access to the resources only if they satisfy the policy. The policy is an logical expression. For example:

> (not A1) and (A2 OR A3) and (2 of (A4, A5,A6))

2 of (A4,A5,A6) refers that it is true only if 2 or more of A4,A5,A6  is true.

"AllOf" and "AnyOf" can be used to express "AND" and "OR", but I don't know how to express "2 of (A4,A5,A6)" and "not A1".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the requirement you have, you need to use a XACML condition. Conditions live within rules only so this means you'll have to put your logic inside the rule.

This is because you will need a function not allowed in XACML targets: n-of.

This is also because a XACML Target cannot have negative expressions. The only way you can express Not(A1) is via a condition.

The reason for that is that XACML deals with attribute bags. So when you write in a target:

```
role==manager
```

What you are in fact saying is: if the user has at least one role equal to manager...

So what would the opposite of that be?

With respect to your 2 of (a,b,c), you can use the XACML function called n-of (urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:n-of defined in [A.3.5 Logical functions](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-os-en.html#_Toc325047244))

The outcome is in [ALFA](https://www.axiomatics.com/axiomatics-alfa-plugin-for-eclipse.html)

```
/**
 * (not A1) and (A2 OR A3) and (2 of (A4, A5,A6))
 */
policy stackoverflow{
    apply firstApplicable
    rule so{
        condition not(A1=="some value") && (A2=="" || A3=="") && nOf(2, stringOneAndOnly(A4)=="value", stringOneAndOnly(A5)=="value", stringOneAndOnly(A6)=="value")
        permit
    }
}
```

In the example above I made A1 through A6 string attributes instead of boolean to show how you would compare with values. Note that I have to use the stringOneAndOnly function to make sure there is a single value for each of the attributes used in the nOf function.

The XACML output is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!--This file was generated by the ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com). 
 Any modification to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file-->
<xacml3:Policy xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
    PolicyId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/policing.principles.stackoverflow"
    RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable"
    Version="1.0">
    <xacml3:Description>(not A1) and (A2 OR A3) and (2 of (A4, A5,A6))</xacml3:Description>
    <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
        <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
    </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
    <xacml3:Target />
    <xacml3:Rule 
            Effect="Permit"
            RuleId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/policing.principles.stackoverflow.so">
        <xacml3:Description />
        <xacml3:Target />
        <xacml3:Condition>
            <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
                <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:not" >
                    <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
                        <xacml3:Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
                        <xacml3:AttributeValue
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">some value</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                            AttributeId="A1"
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                            Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                            MustBePresent="false"
                        />
                    </xacml3:Apply>
                </xacml3:Apply>
                <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
                    <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:or">
                        <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
                            <xacml3:Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"></xacml3:AttributeValue>
                            <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                                AttributeId="A2"
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                                MustBePresent="false"
                            />
                        </xacml3:Apply>
                        <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
                            <xacml3:Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"></xacml3:AttributeValue>
                            <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                                AttributeId="A3"
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                                MustBePresent="false"
                            />
                        </xacml3:Apply>
                    </xacml3:Apply>
                    <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:n-of" >
                        <xacml3:AttributeValue
                            DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">2</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                            <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only" >
                                <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                                    AttributeId="A4"
                                    DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                    Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                                    MustBePresent="false"
                                />
                            </xacml3:Apply>
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">value</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        </xacml3:Apply>
                        <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                            <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only" >
                                <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                                    AttributeId="A5"
                                    DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                    Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                                    MustBePresent="false"
                                />
                            </xacml3:Apply>
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">value</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        </xacml3:Apply>
                        <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                            <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only" >
                                <xacml3:AttributeDesignator 
                                    AttributeId="A6"
                                    DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                                    Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource"
                                    MustBePresent="false"
                                />
                            </xacml3:Apply>
                            <xacml3:AttributeValue
                                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">value</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                        </xacml3:Apply>
                    </xacml3:Apply>
                </xacml3:Apply>
            </xacml3:Apply>
        </xacml3:Condition>
    </xacml3:Rule>
</xacml3:Policy>
```

--- EDIT ---

To express negative conditions e.g. not(gender==male), you have two options:

- either the set of possible values is finite e.g. true/false, male/female, hot/warm/cold and you are happy building a policy or rule per case.
- or the set of possible values is too long or infinite e.g. a numerical value or a list of citizenships (180+ of those).

In the former case you can write the following:

```
policy checkGender{
    apply firstApplicable
    rule male{
        target clause gender=="male"
        permit
    }
    rule female{
        target clause gender=="female"
        permit
    }
    /**
     * Optionally add a catch all case
     */
    rule other{
        target clause ... // Here you'd have to define other checks you are interested in
    }
}
```

In the latter case, you need to write a negative condition. To do that you need to use a XACML condition. Since XACML conditions only live inside rules, you need to go down to the XACML Rule level.

```
policy checkGender{
    apply firstApplicable
    rule notMale{
        condition not(gender=="male")
        permit
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But there is another problem using "NOT". I'd like to express a policy like "NOT male" that is not "NOT gender=='male'". The operation "NOT" works on value but not on attribute. How could I do that? Thank you.

Comment: That's part of my answer. If you want to express a NOT policy, you need to use a XACML condition inside a XACML Rule. You could also list all possible values. You have to be male or female so you could have a female policy, a male policy and possibly a policy where the value isn't specified.

Comment: I have added an example. Don't forget to accept the answer if it is the right one.

Comment: "not(male)" only have attribute value and don't have attribute name "gender" or without AttributeId in the example. An request may also only send value like "female" without it's attribute name gender. I don't think that will work.

Comment: In a XACML request, you cannot just send a value. You always send an attribute with 0 or more values. You would always say gender=male.

Comment: OK, I got it. There also can't exist just a value without attribute name in XACML policy. Thank you!